Question restructuring
Question
Influence: 

http://www.ted.com/conversations/18501/are_people_really_more_narciss.html 
http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2012/mar/17/facebook-dark-side-study-aggressive-narcissism 
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/05/01/teenagers-values-materialistic-work_n_3193782.html
http://blogs.berkeley.edu/2014/06/26/are-we-more-self-absorbed-than-previous-generations-or-more-self-aware/ 
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140911175326-66132034-social-media-and-narcissism-rise-of-a-self-obsessed-society 
http://www.psychalive.org/obsession-with-selfies/ 
http://www.telegraph.co.uk/women/womens-life/11265022/Selfie-obsession-are-we-the-most-narcissistic-generation-ever.html

What can I do to restructure my question so that it wouldn't, elicit (fully) opinion based answers?
@Josh    /  @JoshGitlin 

You should add some of the references you include here to your original question. That way if somebody doesn't believe you opinion-based claim that "people are becoming more egotistical", you will have left them some evidence. You will have motivated your question.
However, please be respectful to the people that read and answer your questions. Don't just drop a bunch of links on us, as you did here. Nobody has the time or interest to click through your links and see what they say, especially without context and when they are mostly linking to not-the-best-of sources for scientific discussion (although of course, we should evaluate that on a link by link basis; but we aren't going to do that with 7 context-less links that a stranger posted on the internet). Put your evidence in context, explain what it is that people are saying and who is saying it, with the links providing corroboration and citation. Do this concisely.
Show us that you did some initial research and reflection. For more information, see: How do I ask a good question?

I'm trying to reach out to the mods on chat. I've posted some stuff there I would like to discuss. I can't ping you though. Could you come over to the axon terminal? It's rather urgent (new pro-tem mod stuff). Thanks.
